# How to multiplying, multiple inputs from using while loop in c

Tags: c

I have to multiply digits by taking input from the user and when he enter 'n' it will produce the answer.

For example (2*3*2 = 12). But I manage to write the code for taking two inputs but can't find the way to take multiple inputs from user and produce the total answer. Here is the code;

```
void main (void)
            {
                float f1,f2;
                float total;
                int status1,status2;
                printf("Enter first number to multiply:'n' to quit.\n ");
                status1=scanf("%f",&f1);
                printf("Enter another number to be multiply:'n' to quit.\n ");
                status2=scanf("%f",&f2);
                while (status1==1 && status2==1)
                    {
                        total=f1*f2;
                        status1=scanf("%1.0f",&f1);
                        status2=scanf("%1.0f",&f2);
                    }
                printf("Multiplition Total = %1.0f",total);
                getch();
            }
```

Comment: @Macmade No, seriously I am new in programming and I am learning C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do what you need and handles, 0, 1 or an unlimited number of inputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float f1;
    float total = 0;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    if (scanf("%f",&total))
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            printf("Enter number: ");
            if (!scanf("%f", &f1))
            {
                break;
            }
            total *= f1;
        }
    }

    printf("Multiplication Total = %f\n",total);

    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

It keeps a running total as values are entered but it stops on first invalid input, not just when `n` is entered.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. But I have a question that can I by any mean write the statement of if with the statement of while. (by using && or || operators).

Comment: I have edited the code to add the write of the question. Note, this answer has recieved a downvote so there may be a mistake (I don't what mistake I have made and downvoter has not provided a reason for the downvote).

Comment: BTW, if you just need to process integers change `float` to `int` and `scanf()`/`printf()` format specifier to `%d`.

Comment: That's exactly the same solution as mine, but coded a little less efficiently (and without the fflush calls which should be needed, but apparently aren't on Turbo C).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop, as follows.

```
 float prod = 1, f;

 printf( "Enter the numbers, n to stop.\n" );
 while( scanf( "%f", &f ) )
   prod *= f;
 printf( "product = %f\n", prod );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can i use without bounding the user for put input not more than 100, I mean can I do it without max input limits.

Comment: Yes you may calculate the product on the fly, like shown in the edited code.

Answer (score 1):

Tested:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int total = 1, factor = 1, success;
    do
    {
        total *= factor;
        printf("Enter integer number to multiply or 'n' to quit: ");
        success = scanf("%d", &factor);
    }
    while (success);
    printf("Multiplication Total = %d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

And a piece of advice as you said you start your adventure with C:
Unless you have some specific reason to do otherwise, use **double**, not float.
However, in your question you asked for digits (integer) multiplication, so int is sufficient. If you can avoid floating point numbers, avoid them. They're much more complicated then integers and can let you in worse problems if you don't use them with caution.
You can refer to [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
float f, p = 1;

printf ("Enter a number: ");
fflush (stdout);
while (scanf("%f", &f) != EOF)
  {
    p *= f;
    printf ("Enter another number: ");
    fflush (stdout);
  }

printf ("Product: %f\n", p);
```

Comment: Just for your info. Iam using Turbo C 3.0 compiler. Thank you

Comment: The above is (a fragment of) standard C. If your compiler can't cope with that then it's not a C compiler. ;)   You'll need to wrap it in a function, of course.

Comment: Sorry not worked the code for me, as my compiler does not support fflush() functtion...any other solution?

Comment: @AbdulAziz Yes, there is another solution...  Install a real C compiler. ;)

Comment: @Gandaro Thanks for the kind advice. But can you advice me compiler better that Turbo C 3.0 compiler. I mean simpler and efficient that this one. please

Comment: If fflush won't work, just omit it, and see what happens. In traditional C you'd probably find that the "Enter ..." messages don't print, but you never know in Turbo C. That problem can be fixed by adding `\n` to the end of the messages. I just prefer to enter the numbers on the end of the prompt, rather than on the next line.